# Можно ли запустить два Telegram бота одновременно в одном исполняемом файле?

Tags: python, telebot

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы, запуская один .py файл, одновременно запускались 2 Telegram бота, которые взаимодействуют друг с другом? Два отдельных файла- не вариант, так как боты должны взаимодействовать друг с другом (например, при присылаемой команде одному боту другой бот присылает вопрос человеку. Человек отвечает на вопрос, и ответ присылается первым ботом некоему админу)

Comment: странную конструкцию вы пытаетесь соорудить...если вам от ботов нужно то, что вы описали, то с этим и один вполне справится, не нужно для этого плодить целую ферму ботов

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать создать Bat файл в котром поместить команды по запуску двух-трех ботов , и запускать все с него